# chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, raspberry-pi2

On my raspberry pi I recently got some weird issues with using `webdriver.Firefox` so I decided to switch to chromedriver, which I am more used to anyway, as I use it when testing stuff on my desktop. I freshly installed chromedriver and made sure chromium was on the latest version, but I got the following error when trying to run my program:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

So I looked on the internet for possible solutions, but the ones I could find either didn't involve chromedriver (I still tried some of those solutions but it didn't work), or involved updating chromium/chromedriver, which are already up-to-date. Just to be sure I also updated selenium python, but that didn't help either.

To be more clear, it's throwing that error on the following line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

Not a duplicate of [WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co), since, as I've mentioned, certain things (including the anwers to thatq uestion) didn't work for me, moreover, I'm using a different OS.

Comment: Looks like there’s a mismatch of the chromedriver version. Make sure the version of chromedriver you’re using supports the version of chromium you’re using.

Comment: Where can I find which versions of chromedriver support which versions of chromium? Seems a bit weird that the most recent versions of both are not compatible with eachother :|

Comment: I wonder why someone marked this as a duplicate - I'm using a different OS as far as I know (I'm not very familiar with the different versions of Linux), and as I clearly stated in my question some answers didn't work for me, including those in the one he marked as duplicate.

Comment: try sudo apt-get install chromium-driver

Comment: the above comment worked?

Comment: lemme try that in a sec.

Comment: `unable to locate package`

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver.  m-chromedriver 61.0.3163.79-0ubuntu0.14.04.1196 in armhf (Updates) download this file

Comment: @Treehee Have you find how to do it my friend?

Comment: Nope. I assume it is indeed a version mismatch, but have no clue where to find which version of chromedriver supports which version of chromium.

Comment: @Treehee handy SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version