# My python scripts using selenium don't work anymore. Chrome driver version problem

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, version

My scripts don't work anymore and I can't figure it out.
It is a chrome version problem apparently... But I don't know how to switch to another version (not the latest?) Does exist another way?

My terminal indicates :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/.../Documents/SCRIPTS/PYTHON/Scripts/# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-.py", line 21, in 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in **init**
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64)

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome version must be between 71 and 75 error after updating to ChromeDriver 2.46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940853/chrome-version-must-be-between-71-and-75-error-after-updating-to-chromedriver-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your test with ChromeDriver & Chrome browser, from the log given, i can see the **ChromeDriver** was not compatible with your current **Chrome Browser**. Because the ChromeDriver version 2.46 aims to support Chrome browser from **v71-v73**. (You can refer to the ChromeDriver change log here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads ). Since v75, there's a major and notable change is ChromeDriver now runs in W3C standard compliant mode by default.

The easiest way is to download the newer ChromeDriver which is compatible with your current Chrome Browser rather than sticking with the old , non supported ChromeDriver version.

Answer (score 0):

This possibly happens, as your Chrome Browser or Chromium may be updated to newer versions automatically. But you still run your selenium scripts using the old version of the chromedriver.

Check the current version of your Google chrome or Chromium, then download the chromedriver for that specific version.

Then your scripts may work fine!