# Chrome failed to start - Chrome version 75.0.3770.100

Tags: selenium, jenkins, headless

We have selenium tests in C# running on jenkins. With the latest version of Chrome 75 the tests are starting to fail during execution with the error "Chrome failed to start"

I went through some articles and have implemented the below code as part of my arguments for Chrome.

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--enable-automation");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-print-preview");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-software-rasterizer");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");                    
chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
```

This happens during jenkins execution only.

Comment: Not familiar with Jenkins, but I would check the path to chrome and check to be sure chrome has been run at least once.  (it sets up certain files/folders on first run...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which ChromeDriver version is compatible with which Chrome Browser version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this on Chrome 76. The solution seems to be to remove the `--disable-software-rasterizer` argument.