# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process error with ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to code basic python-Google Chrome interactions with webdriver but I constantly get the same error while trying to launch a link on my browser.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class Instagrambot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = Instagrambot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
```

I have the chromedriver in the current directory, and I am using the correct version of the chromedriver (79.0.3945.36) for my browser (Chrome 79.0.3945.88) . The full error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Arthur/Documents/instabot/bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    ig_bot = Instagrambot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
  File "c:/Users/Arthur/Documents/instabot/bot.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response 
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
```

I have already tried:

Writing the full executable path towards chromedriver.exe (same folder of bot.py)

Overriding the Chrome binary location as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078276/11206079

If anyone can help me or give any insight about how to fix it I would be really glad!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version, the driver need to be of certian version, i faced this earlier as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

I don't see any such issue in your code block. However, a bit more details about your *Test Environment* with respect to version of the binaries and user type you are using would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However most possibly you are executing your test as an **administrator**

---

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

### Additional considerations

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.