# WebdriverIO - Unable to run test runner due to error in chrome/chromedriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to setup UI automation using webdriver IO. I saw the below repo and have been trying to set the project up and running with very little success.

https://github.com/openfin/webinar-automated-integration-tests

I did all the required changes and fixed all the issues that came up in the process. Now, the hello world UI appears but the tests don't run. Nothing happens in the UI as well. When I run the tests I see the below error

```
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:02:54.321Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Please find below the console logs when I run the test.

```
Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-02-11T12:59:48.259Z

2020-02-11T12:59:48.263Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2020-02-11T12:59:48.542Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
Application hosted locally on port 4000
[0-0] 2020-02-11T12:59:49.815Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\test\hello-world.js
[0-0] 2020-02-11T12:59:50.119Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-02-11T12:59:50.121Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:9515/session
[0-0] 2020-02-11T12:59:50.122Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities:
   { browserName: 'chrome',
     'goog:chromeOptions': { extensions: [], binary: 'RunOpenFin.bat', args: [Array] } } }
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:00:51.984Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:00:51.985Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
2020-02-11T13:00:51.985Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:9515/session
2020-02-11T13:00:51.985Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities:
   { browserName: 'chrome',
     'goog:chromeOptions': { extensions: [], binary: 'RunOpenFin.bat', args: [Array] } } }
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:01:52.511Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:01:52.511Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 2/3
2020-02-11T13:01:52.511Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:9515/session
2020-02-11T13:01:52.511Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities:
   { browserName: 'chrome',
     'goog:chromeOptions': { extensions: [], binary: 'RunOpenFin.bat', args: [Array] } } }
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:02:54.321Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:02:54.321Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 3/3
2020-02-11T13:02:54.321Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:9515/session
2020-02-11T13:02:54.321Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities:
   { browserName: 'chrome',
     'goog:chromeOptions': { extensions: [], binary: 'RunOpenFin.bat', args: [Array] } } }
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:03:56.156Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:124:10)
    at Request._callback (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\webdriver\build\request.js:111:64)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
[0-0] Error: Failed to create session.
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
[0-0] 2020-02-11T13:03:56.157Z ERROR webdriver: Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:124:10)
    at Request._callback (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\webdriver\build\request.js:111:64)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
2020-02-11T13:03:56.157Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
    at startWebDriverSession (C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:45:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - C:\Git\webinar-automated-integration-tests\test\hello-world.js
2020-02-11T13:03:56.565Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:04:08

2020-02-11T13:03:56.567Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2020-02-11T13:03:56.819Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2020-02-11T13:03:56.819Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

I am using Chrome version "66.0.3359.181" and Chrome driver version 2.38

I am stuck with this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried chromedriver v2.39 or v2.40?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618567/9083532

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes. I had tried both 2.39 and 2.40. They result in a different error



webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist