# Disable "Disable developer mode extensions" popup in ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

Well, I'm trying to disable this popup, because a `NoSuchElementException` occurs because this is interfering on the UI.

[image: ...]

```cs
private static ChromeDriver CreateDriver()
        {
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            //{
            //    BinaryLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "chromedriver/chromedriver"),
            //};

            /*
             // ONLY FOR TESTING IN WINDOWS
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            //chromeOptions.AddArgument("window-size=932,1025");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
            */

            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions-file-access-check");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");

            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--lang=en");

            // --disable-extensions-file-access-check

            //chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

            chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");

            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36");

            if (IsLinux)
            {
                // Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version
                // https://chromium.woolyss.com/

                var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

                service.LogPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "logs", "client.log");
                service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

                chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

                //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
                //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
                //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1280,800");
                //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");

                //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
                //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
                //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

                return new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
            }

            return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        }
```

This options is what I tried, but the popup is still showing.

```
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions-file-access-check");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
```

In Java I saw this option also: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");`

But obviously I don't have any change to reimplement this on C#. So I don't know where can I continue.

This popup shows only when the `chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");` option is exposed (this is obligatory in Linux). So I don't know what do exactly.

Any help here would be wonderful!

**Note:** I'm using `ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36`

Comment: I posted this question because this question didn't resolved anything. I think it's not neccesary to close any question, because any of the solutions I tried has worked.

Comment: It might sound goofy, but try removing the double dashes from the argument names. For instance use `AddArgument("disable-extensions")` instead.

Comment: Thanks @GregBurghardt for you quick answer! But I tried this also without luck. :(

Comment: Ok, now it's working, but right now password field is also interfering with the UI. Thanks. This is my code: https://pastebin.com/pm7nJE4a

Comment: Try this, short answer, worked for me 
            options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");