# my chromedriver opens and crashes immediately

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use pycharm and I have installed chrome driver and selenium(added a path to the driver and everything).

I tried re-installing but it doesn't work.

I run a basic code for opening chrome

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver=webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

after it crashes it brings this errors

```py
File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(

File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response 
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I looked at every tutorial, but nothing fixed it.

Comment: Are you using the latest chromedriver? Also, shouldn't it be webdriver.Chrome()?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like an issue of ChromeDriver not being compatible with the version of Chrome Browser that you are using.

This post tells which version of ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser go together: [Which ChromeDriver version is compatible with which Chrome Browser version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version/49618567#49618567)

This link is a place where you can download older versions of ChromeDriver: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html