# What is the correct WebDriver to use for Chromium version 78.0.3904.108

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I am trying to do some web scraping using Selenium. This is being done on a Raspberry Pi where the default browser is Chromium. 
I need the WebDriver that will work with Chromium. Does ChromeDriver also work with Chromium because I have tried the ChromeDriver versions that are closest to my Chromium browser version (as the exact same one isn't listed) and it is not currently working but I don't know if this is to do with it being the wrong driver version or driver altogether?

I have currently tried to use the versions either side of my Chromium version for the ChromeDriver as there isn't one matching the exact Chromium version.
The 2 versions I have tried are 78.0.3904.105 and 78.0.3904.70.

When I run my program it gives me an error of `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error` and I have my line of code written as `driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)`.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think this version would work when its an entire version above the current one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which ChromeDriver version is compatible with which Chrome Browser version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-version-is-compatible-with-which-chrome-browser-version)

Comment: Ok well then if i work on the basis that the driver is working as it should, what would be causing the error i mentioned about?
The driver is sitting in the pi directory so `/home/pi/chromedriver.exe` with my code reading `PATH = "/home/pi/chromedriver.exe"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I'm going to answer my own question after now resolving it with a mix of the help from here and elsewhere. I found that the version of chromedriver i was using for linux was not supported as I am using a RaspberryPi which is arm based and the driver is 64bit based. I was provided with [This link](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases?after=v7.1.5) to github for an electron build of the driver which does support arm. The link goes to the page of the version i used (from december) and this driver has done the job for me. I did not remove chromium at all either.
I hope this helps anyone else that may be running into the same issue

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

You should have the chrome driver version matching your chrome / chromium browser

Releases of ChromeDriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Make sure you add the downloaded executable to your PATH variable or you can specify the path while instancing the webdriver (passing the absolute path in `path` argument)

Comment: I was meant to mention that my chromium version is `78.0.3904.108` and there is no driver version matching that

Comment: @dbhol did you try this one https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.105/

Comment: Yes that is the one i am currently using on my PATH and i'm getting the `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error` error when trying to run the program

Comment: @dbhol Then you should upgrade your chromebrowser to the latest version and use the latest chromedriver release only

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver